# Is it possible to forecast a variable number of points using LSTM neural nets?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, keras, time-series, lstm

I'm currently working on time series forecasting using a LSTM network. The univariate dataset looks like this:
[image]

As shown in the graph, each cycle's period (ranging from a peak to peak) grows over time. Is it possible to train a model to predict a full cycle from this dataset? I've used a Keras LSTM network to accurately predict periodic functions. To do so, I've formatted the data in such a way that an *example* is three cycles worth of points and a *label* is one consecutive cycles worth of points.

I'm just not sure whether this extends to the non-periodic case as each example and label would have a varying number of points as the period grows.

Any suggestions would be really appreciated.